# how to export MAC executable from Flash AIR 4

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I have an adobe air application built in flash cs6 (adobe air 4.x.x) , I am able to export a EXE file (with a captive runtime) for windows ( I am on a windows machine).

However when I export an executable for mac I get a APP file . When i try to run this file on a MAC it says damaged/incomplete.

Can you help me with exporting an executable version for MAC?

Thanks
sidharth

Comment: I think you need to export on a Mac to get a Mac app

Comment: thanks for answering. Yes, i needed to compile in MAC  version of flash cs6 to get a .dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile in MAC version of flash to get a .dmg file.